# react native gif not showing

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to display a gif in my android react-native project but it does not seem to work

my entire class is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  DrawerLayoutAndroid,
  ScrollView,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class Animation extends React.Component {
    render() {

```
return(
    <View>
 <Image source={require('../assets/loading.gif')} />
    </View>
    )
}
}

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
});

module.exports = Animation;
```

When I change the gif to a png in the same file it works perfectly so there is nothing wrong with the path.

To be clear I do not get an error, just nothing shows

Comment: check if the loading.gif is not white and you trying to load on white background....otherwise your code looks fine

Comment: try renaming the .gif file to .png and do not specify format while requiring  <Image source={require('../assets/loading')} />

Comment: Thanks orlando I did search before asking but missed that, will delete